# How can I make a local call on the server to Authentication service?

Tags: authentication, graphql, feathersjs

### I have a working FeathersJS server working with Authentication service.

I can make a POST from the client (browser) like this:

> http://localhost:3030/authentication/
>
> ### POST BODY:
>
> {
>    "strategy": "local",
>    "email": "myEmail",
>    "password": "myPassword"
>   }

That works and it returns validated accessToken.

I am trying to implement GraphQL (Apollo server v.2). I managed to make it working and I can call any Feathers Services from GraphQL resolver.

### The problem is - I need to call Authentication service from the code on Server side and not from the client.

Sure I can just ho ahead and code everything by myself - make a query to Users and validate. But since Authentication service is already in place - can I re-use it?

I can get the service object:

> const authService = app.service('authentication');

Can I just call some function to get the validated accessToken, something like:

> return authService.someFunction( {"strategy": "local","email": "torodom.canada@gmail.com", "password": "password"} );

There are just 2 methods available

### create and remove.

Create does not validate - it just generates JWT based on parameters.

Can someone give me a help or any idea about it?
Appreciate any help.

Comment: OK. I finally found the problem. You have to add "provider" as a parameter to service call. Now it works and does not bypass the verification.

Answer (score 1):

The method to use is standard Feathers service [`create` method](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/services.html#createdata-params):

```
return authService.create({
  "strategy": "local",
  "email": "torodom.canada@gmail.com",
  "password": "password"
});
```

You can learn more about Feathers service in the [basics guide](https://docs.feathersjs.com/guides/basics/services.html) and the authentication service in the [authentication server API documentation](https://docs.feathersjs.com/api/authentication/server.html#appserviceauthentication).

Comment: Daff. Thank you for the help. It still looks like the call to **authService.create** is simply to create JWT. At least for my case - it does not validate the User. It creates the JWT regardless if I supply valid credentials or not. But the HTTP POST request to 'authentication' service  actually validates the user first and returns JWT only if the user credentials are correct. Anyway, it's not a show stopper. Thanks.